# php mysql prepared statements not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This works

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select username from usernames where session" . "1" . " = :session");
$stmt->bindParam(':session', $session);
$stmt->execute();
```

But this does not work

```
$data = "1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select username from usernames where session" . ":data" . " = :session");
$stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
$stmt->bindParam(':session', $session);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have been trying to figure out why. Can some please help.

the only thing I can think of is my database has session1 as a field, but it also has session2, so maybe I cant use parameters to split up a field name?

I have been using

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

but I just get a blank screen
Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php that'll tell you *why* it's failing.

Comment: Prepared statements are not some fancy form of string concatenation. There's a lot more going on than that so you cannot use placeholders for table or column names in a prepared statement. In any case, if you have columns named `session1`, `session2`, etc. you're database design is flawed.

Comment: *"but I just get a blank screen"* => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

This definitely won't work as it'll be passing `$data` as a string, meaning you effectively get something like `where session'1' = 'whatever'`. Regardless, I'm fairly sure you can't do this in this manner anyway - the variables are for values, not column/table names.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) is quite similar, and the answers there look like they apply - one of them even specifically mentions columns.